# CSS allign list elements horizontally

Tags: css

This is the HTML markup for a navigation bar:

```
<div class="w-100 justify-content-center p-xl-0 border-bottom">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="uwp-profile-tabs-nav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav flex-wrap m-0 list-unstyled">
                <li id="uwp-profile-posts" class="nav-item  active border-bottom border-primary border-width-2 list-unstyled m-0">
                    <a href=".../posts/" class="nav-link"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i> <span class="uwp-profile-tab-label uwp-profile-posts-label">Meine Beiträge</span></a>
                </li>
                <li id="uwp-profile-shortcode" class="nav-item  list-unstyled m-0">
                    <a href="..." class="nav-link"><i class="fas fa-cubes"></i> <span class="uwp-profile-tab-label uwp-profile-shortcode-label">Favoriten</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

However, the items of the bar are aligned vertically and on the right.

[image]

I have tried multiple ways, the closest I got was to align the items on the left with

```
div.w-100 {
    display:flex;
}
```

The list elements show up on the left side, but are still not ordered horizontally

Comment: Is this about Bootstrap? version? or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the CSS code:

```
flex-direction: row;
```

Edit - This is the correct code:

```
.navbar-nav {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
}

.navbar-nav li {
margin-right: 3em; /* This adds a margin for every <li> item. Set it to whatever you want */ }
```

Comment: unfortunately no change

Comment: @Roland check the edit on my original post. I just tested that and it works